# Как починить автодеплой GIT настроен через bitbucket-pipelines.yml на bitbucket.org?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Когда-то один программист настроил мне автодеплой в моем репозитории на **bitbucket.org** через файл **bitbucket-pipelines.yml**, чтобы все правки с ветки **DEV** автоматически отображались на **тестовом** сайте.

Вчера на **bitbucket.org**, после входа в систему, я увидел какое-то сообщение о том, что они были вынуждены изменить ключи доступа или что-то в этом роде... точно не помню. В сообщении содержалась ссылка на статью, в которой говорилось, какую команду я должен выполнить, чтобы обновить ключи.

Я выполнил команду. На сервере, где лежат ssh-ключи, файл "**known_hosts**" обновился и в этом файле внизу появился новый ключ, который начинается с bitbucket.org ssh-ed25519....

После этого автодеплой перестал работать... Я вижу в лог-файле эту ошибку - "**fatal: Could not upload. Can't access remote 'ftp://xxftp:***@xx.xх.х.хх'. Network down? Wrong URL?**"

Вот такой код у меня в файле **bitbucket-pipelines.yml** сейчас и который работал все время:

```
image: php:8.2.5-fpm
pipelines:
  branches:
    dev:
    - step:
        name: Deploy to dev
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip git git-core git-ftp
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST_PATH
```

Если нужно, [вот полный код с лог файла pipelines](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o7bCdw3R-QW34doynkUu3_eB5T3c2W_gbeUXpmb5Cy0/edit)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне нужно изменить в файле **bitbucket-pipelines.yml** или может что-то другое нужно сделать, чтобы автодеплой снова начал работать? Заранее благодарен за помощь

Comment: вы руками попробуйте выполнить упавшую команду `git ftp catchup....`, добейтесь чтобы она работала - она не может достучаться на сервер.  там что-то простое - либо URL неверный, либо пароль

Comment: мне кажется, в yml всё ок, вы не можете залогиниться на сервер.  у вас в инструкции была команда `ssh-copy-id` ?  вы её выполнили?

Comment: ESkri, спасибо за ваш ответ. Понимаю, что что-то простое.... Но не знаю как починить.... Я нашел статю в которой написано что нужно сделать - https://bitbucket.org/blog/ssh-host-key-changes - в ней нет команды ssh-copy-id...

Я выполнил команду - ssh-keygen -R bitbucket.org && curl https://bitbucket.org/site/ssh >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts. После этого я снова выполняю команду - ssh git@bitbucket.org host_key_info и вот что я вижу - https://prnt.sc/XZog6TuR63VI

Comment: сайт `prnt.sc` заблокирован роскомнадзором, не вижу картинку

Comment: в статье написано, что `No action is required for user-generated SSH keys`, значит `ssh-copy-id` вам не нужна

Comment: напиши мне в ТГ, пожалуйста @vl_stil

Comment: зашёл с другого девайса, увидел картинку, у вас какие-то старые недействительные ключи в known_hosts, удалите (переименуйте) этот файл и создайте его заново (этими же командами с картинки)

Comment: В моем случае помогло в настройках репозитория в "Repository variables" изменение переменной в которой был прописан путь до директории с файлами проекта на такой - sftp://адрес-сервера:22/путь/к-директории/проекта/ и перегенерация SSH ключей - может кому-то поможет